# Custom derivation path

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, bip44

Instead of using `bip32 or bip44` paths what if I use a custom derivation path,
For example:  `m/0/0/55/1/1/0`

I am thinking even if the private key is exposed then can someone guess the derivation path ?

Comment: If the private key for an address is exposed you don't need to guess the derivation path

Comment: Ie the above paths private key is exposed and using that private key anyone can get the other private keys ie  address 0,1,2,3

Comment: So are there any advantages in having custom derivation paths ?

Comment: Some projects use them to specify derivation schemes not covered by BIP44. Otherwise, not really. The whole point of the path is to create a standard, reproducible flow.